# Entity Framework Async Performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Estou implementando um webapi de forma assíncrona, e testei duas formas de retornar o valor com EF6. A 1º forma foi utilizando ToListAsync(), e a 2º forma foi utilizando Task. A 2º forma tem uma performance bem melhor que a segunda. Fiquei na dúvida se devo utilizar a 2º forma ou a 1º.

Código utilizando ToListAsync()

```
public Task<List<Holiday>> All()
{
    return _dbSet.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
}
```

Código utilizando Task

```
public Task<List<Holiday>> All()
{
    return Task.FromResult(_dbSet.AsNoTracking().ToList());
}
```

Código da Controller que chama esses métodos:

```
public async Task<ObjectResult> Get()
{
    try
    {
        var result = await _appService.All();

        return this.Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return this.BadRequest("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Se não me engano o `Task.FromResult()` roda de forma síncrona, então só a primeira realmente é assíncrona

Comment: "*A 2º forma tem uma performance bem melhor que a segunda*". Qual delas tem uma performance bem melhor?

Comment: Oi @jbueno
public Task<List<Holiday>> All()
{
    return Task.FromResult(_dbSet.AsNoTracking().ToList());
}

Answer (score 5):

O primeiro está sendo utilizado de forma errada. O método precisa ser `public async Task<List<Holiday>>` e você deve utilizar o `await` (igual à action do teu *Controller*):

```
public async Task<List<Holiday>> All()
{
    return await _dbSet.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

---

Use métodos assíncronos sempre que disponíveis (ex: o EF disponibiliza, logo procure utilizá-lo sempre que puder). No caso de aplicações *server*, isso ajuda/facilita a escalabilidade no que diz respeito à capacidade do IIS de atender requisições. Em aplicações GUI, o `await/async` faz com que a tela não fique travada enquanto algum código é executado e/ou esteja aguardando a resposta de algum recurso (consulta a um banco de dados, chamada a API, *webservices*).

**TL;DR**

### O exemplo do café e da água

Imagina que em uma mesa tenha um bebedouro d'água, uma garrafa de café e copos de vidro, mas tem **poucos** copos. As pessoas que chegaram na frente pegam o copo para utilização (seja para água ou café). Algumas pessoas ficaram sem copo, portanto deverão esperar as demais terminarem de utilizar, para então - após lavar o copo - utilizá-lo.

O problema é que a **garrafa de café está vazia**. Daí, quem queria café fica ali com o copo na mão esperando até terminarem de passar o café e encherem a garrafa, impedindo as demais pessoas que ficaram sem copo e queriam água de utilizarem o copo (pois como eram poucos copos, não tinha para todo mundo). Sacanagem, né? Daria tempo de outras pessoas tomarem água, lavar o copo e devolver à pessoa do café que continuava esperando.

O café e a água são **recursos**, os copos são as *threads* da *pool* de *threads* do IIS para atenderem requisições, as pessoas são os clientes (sejam  usuários ou outras aplicações fazendo requisições) que irão consumir esses recursos.

Utilizando código assíncrono, seria como a pessoa do café não manter o copo com ela (o método não bloqueia a *thread* do IIS) enquanto **aguarda trazerem café** (enquanto o método aguarda o retorno de uma consulta no banco, ou uma chamada a uma API/WCF), liberando o copo para outra pessoa utilizar (o método com `await` libera a thread para outras requisições serem atendidas).

Se o café chegar rápido, pode ocorrer dessa pessoa ter que **esperar** enquanto a outra termina de beber água, para que ele possa beber seu café (ou seja, se a consulta terminar, pode ser que aquela *action* precise esperar ter uma *thread* disponível para continuar sua execução e retornar ao usuário), ou pode ser que a pessoa já tenha terminado de beber sua água (a segunda requisição já terminou e liberou a *thread* de volta para a primeira requisição que originalmente tinha utilizado aquela *thread*).

Com certeza, de forma assíncrona, o tempo de espera total para os dois (somando tudo) é menor do que de forma síncrona.

Por outro lado, se todas as pessoas quisessem o café, aí não teria jeito: todo mundo teria que esperar (ou seja, se todas as requisições fossem uma consulta ao banco de dados e o mesmo estivesse travado, não ajudaria muito, pois todos iriam ficar esperando de qualquer forma).

---

Não sei o que você quis dizer com *a 2ª forma ter performance **bem melhor** do que a "segunda"*, mas se você fizer testes, a utilização de métodos *Async* (como o `ToListAsync` ao invés de apenas `ToList`) **utilizam sim** uma "sobrecarga" (processamento) um pouco maior, tornando-o mais lento, entretanto asseguro que a diferença é tão pequena que não deveria causar o menor impacto em sua aplicação.

A utilização de rotinas assíncronas em aplicações GUI (como WPF e WinForms) serve para **não travar** a "tela", deixando a aplicação com responsividade  enquanto aguarda o retorno de algum método/recurso externo (como uma chamada a uma API, WebService, consulta a um banco de dados e outras operações de I/O). Já em aplicações *server* (WCF e WebApplication, por exemplo), se trata de liberar o atendimento a novas requisições por parte do IIS, ajudando na escalabilidade do mesmo.

Eu entendo que você deveria utilizar os métodos *Async* (como `ToListAsync()`) sempre que disponível pelas bibliotecas (como EF6) que você venha a utilizar.

Não significa que você estará trabalhando com paralelismo e nem que isso deixará seus métodos mais rápidos (na verdade, como em alguns casos eles podem iniciar uma nova *thread* para a execução de uma dessas rotinas, tem o custo de processamento para criação dessa nova *thread*, e depois o custo para voltar à *thread* principal), mas isso facilita quando houver necessidade de escalar sua aplicação.

> Para um entendimento melhor, eu sugiro a leitura dessa [publicação do
>   Stephen Cleary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx), ele é mito nesse assunto.

---

### Exemplo com requisições síncronas

Apenas um exemplo simples: suponhamos a *pool* de *threads* do IIS tivesse apenas 2 *threads* para atendimento de requisições, e você esteja utilizando apenas métodos síncronos.

Digamos que um primeiro usuário acessou uma página, que vai invocar uma action, que chamará uma API externa (paypal, facebook, qualquer outra coisa) e essa operação demora alguns segundos. Uma *thread* é consumida para a requisição (restando apenas 1) e sua *action* aguardará sincronamente o retorno dessa API.

Enquanto isso, outro usuário acessou outra página, que irá consultar algo no banco de dados para fazer algum tipo de processamento (que demore mais alguns segundos). Outra *thread* é utilizada e só será liberada quando a *action* do controller retornar uma resposta.

Se um terceiro usuário tentar acessar outra página qualquer, a requisição dele ficará aguardando até uma das duas *threads* anteriores serem liberadas, ou seja, somente quando uma das *actions* terminar sua execução (que depende de recursos externos, como API e banco de dados, que por sua vez podem demorar).

### O mesmo exemplo, porém de forma assíncrona

Quando a primeira *action* fizer a chamada a uma API externa utilizando `await`, a *thread* do IIS volta a ficar disponível, de forma que quando chegar aquele terceiro usuário, a requisição dele será imediatamente atendida.

Suponhamos que essa terceira requisição consumiu a *thread* que estava livre (que tinha sido original utilizada pela primeira requisição) e a segunda esteja fazendo algum processando, ocupando a outra *thread*. Ou seja, as duas *threads* estão ocupadas nesse momento. Caso a API na primeira requisição tenha retornado com uma resposta, o comportamento padrão será a *action* tentar recuperar a *thread* do IIS novamente para continuar sua execução, mas não conseguirá pois as duas estão ocupadas.

Essa terceira requisição faz uma chamada a um WCF em um servidor de *backend* para fazer algum processamento, utilizando `await`, liberando a *thread*, que será consumida pela primeira requisição, apenas para terminar a *action* e devolver uma resposta ao usuário, liberando novamente a *thread*, e a terceira requisição obteve um retorno do WCF e consumiu novamente a *thread*, também para apenas terminar a *action* e devolver resposta ao usuário.

Nesse caso, o tempo que a *thread* fica ocupada com alguma das requisições, é só o tempo de entrar na *action* do *controller* e chamar o `await`.

Claro que o IIS aguenta bem mais requisições do que apenas 2, foi só para exemplificar, mas se sua aplicação cresce muito, aí pode ser que comece a fazer diferença. Mas o interessante é utilizar a boa prática desde cedo, ao invés de esperar o problema surgir para depois modificar todo teu código.