# Qual diferença entre async Task e void?

Tags: c#, .net, async, assincronismo

Eu utilizo `async Task` com `await` quando preciso que meu código espere que tal tarefa complete até que execute outro processo.

No caso de métodos `void`, sem `async-await`, meu código também não "espera" para executar um outro processo até que o meu método `void` seja completado para que seja executado?

```
async Task DoFooAsync()
{
    await FooAsync();
    // ...
}

async Task FooAsync()
{
    // minha operação de execução longa
}

void DoFoo()
{
    Foo();
    // ...
}

void Foo()
{
    // minha operação de execução longa
}
```

No exemplo, qual é a diferença na execução dos métodos `DoFooAsync()`, chamado com `await` e `DoFoo`?

Comment: Olá Vinicius. Se você tiver paciência, dá uma lida [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183457/entity-framework-async-performance/187592#187592) que dei a outra pergunta. Eu tentei criar uma analogia para explicar a fila de requisições que o servidor recebe e atende, com e sem utilizar o `async/await`. Foi um exemplo *meio tosco*, mas acho que dá pra pegar a ideia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O segundo exemplo é uma chamada normal **síncrona**, ou seja, `DoFoo()` está executando, em determinado momento transfere o fluxo de execução para `Foo()`, internamente é praticamente um [`goto`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101), quando este termina de executar um outro `goto` é executado voltando para o ponto a seguir onde a chamada de `Foo()` (há alguns detalhes de como ele faz esse controle que não vem ao caso, até por ser interno ao processador).

O primeiro exemplo não deixa de ser duas funções normais, mas a forma de chamada é bem diferente, ela é **assíncrona** que permite que a execução seja liberada para executar outras coisas.

Há uma infraestrutura complexa montada pelo compilador do C# para controlar uma máquina de estado que controla a execução dos métodos. Não só um desvio de fluxo simples. E há um gráfico que mostra como o fluxo se torna complexo:

[image: Fluxo de métodos assíncronos]

Note o fluxo preto como vai e volta de forma normal. O vermelho inicia a execução da função mas pode não terminar permitindo que outro fluxo seja executado dali, até mesmo enquanto aquela função fica esperando respostas externas como disco, rede, serviços e banco de dados.

Então a diferença é que o método assíncrono espera o fim da execução da função mas permite que outro fluxo seja executado, enquanto que o método síncrono fica ali parado esperando o término do processamento.

Mas não tem milagre, de alguma forma é preciso ter uma infraestrutura que acesse o mecanismo externo dando a chance de outro fluxo executar. Se você está só consumindo algo não precisa se preocupar muito, mas se está escrevendo o acesso externo precisa coordenar isso. Veja um exemplo de [como é o acesso à leitura de arquivo assíncrono](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,2c203718e302b739) ([no .NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/FileStream.cs,365)), não é tão trivial.

Sempre existiu a forma assíncrona no .NET, mas era muito complicado consumir porque você tinha que escrever o código para coordenar o fluxo, agora o compilador escreve por você.

Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre a utilidade e funcionamento porque já existem várias respostas para isto:

- [O que são métodos Async?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175304/101)
- [Em C#, para que serve a palavra chave await?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101)
- [Qual diferença entre ToListAsync() e ToList()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/169733/101)
- [Quando usar método assíncronos ou síncronos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/201998/101)
- [A palavra-chave "async" realmente faz o método assíncrono?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168186/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre os async, multithreading, paralelismo e concorrência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157435/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre SmtpClient.SendAsync() e SmtpClient.Send() utilizando Thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156813/101)
- [Utilização correta do async and await no Asp.Net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84209/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Você está comparando uma chamada assíncrona à uma chamada síncrona.

No caso da chamada assíncrona, a `thread` principal será liberada quando houver alguma chamada de `IO`, ou quando estiver esperando o termino de uma operação `CPUBound` sendo executado em outra `thread`. Desta forma, você estará liberando estes recursos para que sejam utilizados por outra operação, como por exemplo atualizar a sua UI.

Já no caso da chamada síncrona, eles recursos irão ficar bloqueados até o final da execução, fazendo que o sistema tenha de alocar mais recursos para executar outros processos, ou ter de esperar até o termino do processo atual.