# Erro retorno método "public async Task<string>"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Quando executo o código abaixo, dá erro nesta linha:

```
Literal1.Text= ObterEmocoes(imageFilePath);
```

Está dando esta mensagem de erro:

> Uma referência de objeto é necessária para o campo, o método ou a propriedade "Program.ObterEmocoes(string)" não estática

Código:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string imageFilePath = @"C:\Users\madureira\Downloads\JRMJ.jpg";
        Literal1.Text= ObterEmocoes(imageFilePath);
    }

    public async Task<string> ObterEmocoes(string imagemBase64)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage respostaHttp;
        string json;
        byte[] bytesImagem = Convert.FromBase64String(imagemBase64);

        string url = "https://brazilsouth.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect";
        string queryString = "returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=age,emotion";

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "2b4d806c1cf5467bb8772f86c3fc0a2e");
        using (var conteudoEmBytes = new ByteArrayContent(bytesImagem))
        {
            conteudoEmBytes.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            respostaHttp = await httpClient.PostAsync($"{url}?{queryString}", conteudoEmBytes);
            json = await respostaHttp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

Comment: você... traduziu a mensagem de erro?

Comment: A mensagem é clara, você precisa criar uma instância da classe. Do jeito que está chamando o método deveria ser estático

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro nesta linha se dá por que você necessita utilizar a keyword `await` antes de chamar o método.

```
Literal1.Text= await ObterEmocoes(imageFilePath);
```

Para isso você precisa marcar o método `Button1_Click` com a keyword `async` ficando assim:

```
protected async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Implementação:

```
protected async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string imageFilePath = @"C:\Users\madureira\Downloads\JRMJ.jpg";
    Literal1.Text= await ObterEmocoes(imageFilePath);
}
```

Referencia

[Qual diferença entre async Task e void?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/224585/44289)

[Em C#, para que serve a palavra chave await?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/44289)

Comment: Deu certo fazendo isso e acrescentando o "<%@ Page  Async="true ..." no ASP. NET.   Muito obrigado!!!!